# get part with regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to get everything bewteen

```
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">
```

and the following `<`

in this case:

```
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">example<
```

I would like to get the word example.
Here is a more complicated example of where it should work as well:

```
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">going to drink?<br></span><span title="Juist!" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ebeff9'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">Exactly!</span></span></div></div>
```

So here i need 2 of them back (and not joined).

Could someone help? I suck at regex.

Someone edited my tag to javascript.
I need a solution to use in java, i just get a file as plain text. So javascript or html solutions are not really helpfull.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2):

Regex with html? Well, If you have to parse only a few lines then ok. But in general is better to use a html parser (because HTML is not a regular language).

This is pure gold: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/434171